# Running a script inside another script

Tags: scripting

I am trying a run a script inside another script as below:

```
$a="$(sh test_part.sh /AB/pass_file.txt)"
echo $a
```

Now `sh test_part.sh /AB/pass_file.txt` returns an output like below:

```
ABD
SDFDR
TDFDG
DGFKFH
```

I want to store that in the variable `$a` as it is. 
With my current script I am getting below error:

```
test_part.sh: line 2: $'=ABD\nSDFDR\nTDFDG\nDGFKFH': command not found
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not have $ prefix while declaring a variable in the shell.

Try as

```
a="$(sh test_part.sh /AB/pass_file.txt)"
echo "$a"
```

or

```
a=($(sh test_part.sh /AB/pass_file.txt))
echo "${a[@]}"
```